# Closing a popup window when user click outside of the popup

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am using silvelight popup control.I have a pop up window it opens when user clicks on a button.I want to close a pop up when user clicks outside of the popup window.

Please let me know how can we do this.

Answer (score 1):

Register a `MouseLeftButtonDownEventHandler` and if you want a `MouseRightButtonDownEventHandler` at the root element of you SL application. Close the PopUp from there. You want to handle even those events that another element already handled (e.g. when the user clicks into a textbox outside the popup).

```
...
var root = System.Windows.Application.Current.RootVisual;
MouseButtonEventHandler handler = HandleRootMouseLeftButtonDown;
root.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, handler, true);
...
private void HandleRootMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    m_popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this not working can you explain more clearly

Comment: @ user3454168: Is it compiling? Is the mouse click event handler registration successful? have you set a breakpoint inside the handler code and is it hit when you click the UI?

Comment: This solved my problem. I already had event handler on form but not the Root, so clicking on a blank area of form did NOT close popup, but clicking on other objects did close popup. I changed my handler to your example, now clicking anywhere outside popup does close popup as expected.